# Dojo cross domain load issue

Tags: dojo

I'm getting a cross domain error when trying to load a custom class.  Here is my directory structure

> lib
>
> > /dijit
> >
> > > /CustomClass1
>
> gic
>
> > /dijit
> >
> > > /CustomClass2

CustomClass2 inherits from CustomClass1, but this is where I'm getting the cross domain error.

I'm including the require in CustomClass2:

```
require("lib.dijit.CustomClass1");
```

I believe I need to add a module path.  I tried the statement below (with many variations) but I haven't gotten it to work. Any ideas?

```
dojo.registerModulePath("gic", "gic");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross domain refers to retrieving the javascript files from a server that is not the domain that is serving the web application itself. An example is loading dojo from a CDN.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/cross-domain.html

From what you posted, I can't tell if you are using dojo from a CDN or not.  If you are, then this link should help you configure your module path:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/cdn/

If not, then it is important to note that the second parameter is a directory path and is relative to dojo.js

```
dojo
  dojo.js
lib
  dijit
gic
  dijit

dojo.registerModulePath("lib", "../lib");
dojo.registerModulePath("gic", "../gic");
```

If you are having this problem doing a custom build, then you need to set prefixes in the profile:

```
prefixes: [
    [ "dijit", "../dijit" ],
    [ "lib", "../lib" ],
    [ "gic", "../gic" ]
]
```